# What happens with lethargy when Haste is cast again on a creature before first cast runs out?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Haste states

> When the spell ends, the target can't move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

However, let's say Character A cast Haste on Character B. In the 10th round (final round of haste if concentration not broken), Character B casts Haste on himself.

What happens during the next round?

1. Do they lose a round of the "new" haste while they are lethargic and lose movement and actions?
2. Does the new haste override the lethargy until it ends?
3. Is it some combination? Retain AC/Dex modifications but lose actions/movement?
4. None of the above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your option 3 is correct.

> When **the spell** ends, the target can’t move or take
>   actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy
>   sweeps over it.

Not "when the target is no longer under this effect" or "when the target no longer has *Haste*"; the condition for losing a turn is when the spell ends. So it doesn't matter that there are 2 spells affecting them simultaneously - if a *Haste* spell ends, you lose a turn.

However, they are still under the effects of a *Haste* spell.

> Until the spell ends, the target’s speed is doubled, it gains
>   a +2 bonus to AC, it has advantage on Dexterity saving
>   throws, and it gains an additional action on each of its
>   turns.

Their speed is still doubled, they still have +2 AC, they still have advantage on Dexterity saving throws, and they still gain an additional action. They can't move, and they can't take actions, but this doesn't prevent them from getting any of those benefits. It just prevents them from *using* some of them.

Answer (score 5):

The real answer is, "Ask your DM", but at my table.

### The new *Haste* (usually) overrides the old one.

The rules for combining effects of the same spell cast multiple times from the PHB:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

They can't be under the effects of both *Haste* spells at once as the other answer suggests, and the clause...

> When the spell ends, the target can’t move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

...is still an effect of the *Haste* spell.

I would apply the spells in order of highest spell level first, followed by longest remaining duration. Your mileage may vary depending on DM. See the question, [How do you determine the 'most potent effect' for overlapping spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93114/how-do-you-determine-the-most-potent-effect-for-overlapping-spells) for various methods of determining the potency of spell effects.

---

Exceptions I haven't considered almost certainly exist. But as a few hypotheticals, casting a second *Haste* spell *after* the first expires wouldn't be overlapping spells. If your wizard stops concentrating on the first *Haste* to cast a second one before it expires, your first one still "ends" and you suffer the consequences before the second one kicks in.

Or a higher level (or otherwise more "potent") *Haste* spell may prevent the new one from taking effect until the original ends.

Either of which creates a scenario like your third option.

See [Will an Antimagic Field on a target of a "Haste" spell trigger the wave of lethargy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99622/will-an-antimagic-field-on-a-target-of-a-haste-spell-trigger-the-wave-of-letha) for another related exceptional hypothetical.