# Dominating an already dominated creature

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

How to interpret using Dominate Person on an already dominated person? Does it sever the initial link? Or does the target hear commands from both links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strongest caster's spell will supress the lower one, so the most powerful spellcaster will be in control.

From the [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/) on spellcasting (bottom of the page):

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

Comment: How do you determine the 'potency' of Dominate Person?  Generally both wizards would cast it at the same level.  What about a tie?  That paragraph seems to cover not stacking bonuses/penalties, but taking the largest one.

Comment: There's a specific question about that, but basically "there is no hard and fast rule" https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93114/how-do-you-determine-the-most-potent-effect-for-overlapping-spells

Comment: First approximation: The higher spell slot level used would win.  If both wizards cast it using the same spell slot level, then the one with the higher spell save DC would be the more potent.  If those are a tie, then it's DM ruling; I'd probably rule the first one cast stays in effect, as the second one failed to beat it.

Comment: @PhilBoncer Actually I would go the other way, longest duration would be the tie breaker and the most recently cast would have the longest duration remaining. But I guess as Erik says that just proves there is no specific rule.

Comment: As I said, that would be DM ruling.  My interpretation is that Duration is different from Potency, and thus I would leave the first one in place of the second one was not stronger.  Where the duration would apply is if the first one stays in effect, for whatever reason (higher spell slot, etc.), then that one prevails, but when that one ends its duration, the second one will take over if it still has duration left.

Comment: Can you guys discuss the potency determination on the other question? ;)