# Can I change appearance multiple times with one casting of Disguise Self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

The Disguise Self spell states:

> You make yourself - including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person - look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it.

A cursory glance at the description has always left me with the impression that you cast it, choose your new appearance, and then you are stuck with that appearance until the spell ends, you cast another, or you dismiss it.

However, one does not have to read it that way.  The spell indicates you can make yourself look different until the spell ends.  It doesn't say you can't constantly change your appearance during that time.

So for example, could I cast the spell to look like a servant, then change my mind and look like a guard?

Comment: @illustro I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. That question's asking what would happen with multiple castings of Disguise Self, this question is asking whether you can change appearance multiple times with only *one* casting.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [What happens when you cast the Disguise Self spell again while currently under its effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122340/what-happens-when-you-cast-the-disguise-self-spell-again-while-currently-under-i)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## No. The change only happens once: Upon casting.

> You make yourself - including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person - **look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it.**

Emphasis mine.  The intent of this line is to state that the change in appearance lasts for the entire duration of the spell, not that you may continuously update your appearance.

There are other spells or abilities that allow you to make modifications or changes during their Duration and they have specific language allowing you to do so. The spell *Alter Self* is the closest example to your question since it deals with changing appearance:

> You transform your appearance. You decide what you look like [...] **At any time for the duration of the spell, you can use your action to change your appearance in this way again.**

Emphasis mine.  The exception proves the rule in this case; since *Alter Self* specifically mentions you are afforded the chance to change.  Spells or abilities that do not denote that you can, do not allow you to.

Answer (score 13):

Nope, you're stuck with the first appearance you choose.

Disguise Self doesn't specifically say you *can't* change your appearance but that doesn't mean you *can* either.

If we look at a spell such as Alter Self, its description specifically says you *can* change your appearance with that spell:

> You transform your appearance. You decide what you look like [...] At any time for the duration of the spell, you can use your action to change your appearance in this way again.

Disguise Self, however, includes no such wording. Therefore you're unable to alter what you look like for the duration of Disguise Self.

Answer (score 12):

## Not unless you are a level 6+ Illusionist Wizard

[OneCritWonder's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123549/can-i-change-appearance-multiple-times-with-one-casting-of-disguise-self/123551#123551) & [Purple Monkey's answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123549/can-i-change-appearance-multiple-times-with-one-casting-of-disguise-self/123550#123550) are correct.

However there is one thing that would allow you to change appearance mid-duration - the [School of Illusion wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion)'s [Malleable Illusions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#MalleableIllusions-442) feature (PHB, p. 118):

> Starting at 6th level, when you cast an illusion spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you can use your action to change the nature of that illusion (using the spell's normal parameters for the illusion), provided that you can see the illusion.

If you had this feature, you could change the appearance created by *disguise self* with an action.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can additionally change the way you look (using this magic).

The description of the magic says very clearly: "You make yourself - including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person - look different until ..."

Magic does not create an image - nowhere in the description of magic does it say that it creates an image. It changes the way you look. And how you look like is a dynamic process.

The illusion can be static only if the creature is also static. Because creature has behavior, the illusion must reflect that behavior. I need to be able to "dress" or "undress" if I make the appropriate movements. I need to be able to take my hat off my head to congratulate a passing higher, etc.

Dozens of simultaneous changes in the illusory appearance are possible and necessary just to move the creature from the shade to the sun / from the covenant to the wind. With an argument for a stronger reason, the creature can focus (systematically use 1 or more actions) and change the way it looks.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to bear any resemblance to the rules of the game. If you're talking about a house rule that you have implemented in a campaign, please state clearly what the rule was and how it worked out. Attempting to compare D&D to the real world usually ends badly...

Comment: The description of the magic says very clearly: "You make yourself - including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person - look different until ..."

Magic does not create an image - nowhere in the description of magic does it say that it creates an image. It changes the way you look. And how you look like is a dynamic process.

The illusion can be static only if the creature is also static. Because creature has behavior, the illusion must reflect that behavior. I need to be able to "dress" or "undress" if I make the appropriate movements.

Comment: You still need to address the original question: "could I cast the spell to look like a servant, then change my mind and look like a guard?"

Comment: Yes, please delete the other answers. Let stay only this answer and comments below.

On the real issue. Yes, it can change.
According to text`s Disguise Self , the magic doesn`t create an image, it changes the way you look. And how you look is a dynamic process. 
Dozens of simultaneous changes in the illusory appearance are possible and necessary just to move the creature from the shade to the sun / from the covenant to the wind.
With an argument for a stronger reason, the creature can focus (systematically use 1 or more actions) and change the way it looks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to delete it - but you can delete your own answer by clicking the 'delete' button at the bottom left of the answer. That's also where you'll find the edit button - this answer **still** needs a clear statement which says something like "Yes/No, you can/can't cast *disguise self* to look like a servant, then change to look like a guard" (delete as appropriate). The rest of your answer can explain why or why not, as clearly as possible, in an 'answer' format rather than a 'discussion' format, with reference to official rules or your own tested house rules.

Comment: Ready. The answer is in accordance with the rules of the forum and I deleted the wrong posts.

Comment: @АнтонФотев Please provide a rules citation to support this answer. You've cited a portion of the spell's text and then applied your own opinion on the matter. I would recommend including citations that adequately address the concerns mentioned here and in your other posts. Namely: Class features that permit what you're allowing the caster to do, the lack of specific rule citations that permit what you're indicating, as well as a specific answer to the querent's cited example regarding changing appearance dramatically to a guard when they started as a servant.

Comment: D&D 5e players hand book, 5 th, May, 2014, 
"Chapter 10: Spell casting", second column of 202 pages, "Casting a Spell",  second pasage: "Each spell description in chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell’s name, level, school
of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. The rest of a spell entry describes the spell’s effect."
To understand whether the effect of magic is subject to secondary change, we must interpret the text itself. The general rules refer to this.
But the text of Disguise Self is clear. It is unnecessary to repeat myself.