# Can lethargy from haste spell's ending be dispelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

Haste description says:

> When the spell ends, **the target can’t move or take actions until after its next turn**, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

**Can this lethargy effect be dispelled using *dispel magic*?** Or maybe supressed inside an antimagic field? Is there any way to cheese out this negative side effect after enjoying *haste*?

Comment: Related: "[Will an Antimagic Field on a target of a "Haste" spell trigger the wave of lethargy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99622)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This effect is not magical at this point, just, as the dictionary definition puts it,

> a lack of energy and enthusiasm.

So, since this is merely an exhaustion equivalent, [dispel magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) and [antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) can not get rid of this effect, and if used during the spell's duration would simply end the spell and cause the exhaustion to happen sooner.

However, there is still a way to get rid the exhaustion, although you would have to talk to your DM about it. The text on the [Greater Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) spell says:

> You can reduce the target's exhaustion level by one...

Since this is a form of exhaustion the argument could be made that this lethargy counts equivalent to a level of exhaustion, but due to the wording of the [Haste](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell, this solution can't be considered RAW, so if your DM doesn't allow it, then there is no other way to get rid of these effects using spells, although you can talk to your DM about finding a magic item to help you as well.

Comment: Small correction, Antimagic Field does not end a spell, but rather it suspends any of its effects.  Without houseruling it, someone with Haste who'd enter an Antimagic field would have Haste continue and end on its normal duration, but have no effects of the Haste spell.  Technically, casting Antimagic Field before Haste ends would mean that you'd suffer no "wave of lethargy" in the last round.  Whether the "wave of lethargy" is a magical curse or kickback doesn't matter; it's still an effect of a spell, and preventing spell effects without ending them is possible via Antimagic Field.

Comment: The lethargy is not exhaustion and does none of the things exhaustion does.

Comment: I know that it is not, and I explain that in my answer. I'm simply pointing out that since Lethargy literally means exhaustion, as stated in my answer, "the argument could be made that this lethargy counts equivalent to a level of exhaustion, but due to the wording of the Haste spell, this solution can't be considered RAW, so if your DM doesn't allow it..."

Comment: You can also lose exhaustion by dying and being raised. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/167519/25662 . The group I GM for was seriously considering it in one case.

Answer (score 9):

### No.

*Dispel Magic* has the following primary effect (from the 5e SRD):

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

Since *Dispel Magic* only ends spells, and the lethargy from *Haste* only occurs after the spell has ended, then *Dispel Magic* would not have any effect on it.

It's arguable whether the lethargy itself is magical, as it explicitly persists after the spell ends and is described in a way that could be a mundane effect, so it would be up to the DM whether an *Antimagic Field* would suppress this penalty.

Comment: Can you make a case for/against why it would be considered magical using what we know about determining if something is magical?