# What level of exhaustion will a Revivified creature have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, resurrection

The [Revivify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/revivify) spell description says:

> You touch a creature that has died within the last minute. That creature returns to life with 1 hit point. This spell can’t return to life a creature that has died of old age, nor can it restore any missing body parts.

If the creature died from  6th level of exhaustion, can it be returned to life with Revivify? What level of exhaustion will it have after the revival?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Level 5 exhaustion

Nothing in the spell description says it affects only those creatures who died from HP loss, so yes, a creature died from exhaustion can be returned to life with Revivify. The target will have level 5 exhaustion afterwards.

This case was explicitly added in the [November 2018 errata](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/rules-game-mechanics/8760-official-wizards-of-the-coast-errata?comment=11):

> being raised from the dead reduces a creature's exhaustion level by l.

Its exhaustion level was 6, so it becomes 5 after the revival.

Fun fact: this presumably means you can remove levels of exhaustion with Revivify (3 lvl spell) instead of Greater Restoration (5 lvl spell) by systematically killing and reviving the target.

Comment: *Greater Restoration* is the more financially efficient way to do it, unless of course your friendly [Zealot Barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#WarrioroftheGods-645) is the one that's all tuckered out...

Comment: @Carcer providing you have access to 5-level spells, yes