# Two instances of Haste with one ending?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

If a creature has two instances of Haste cast on it, and the first one ends, does the character suffer of lethargy? Relevant rules I can find:

“**Combining Magical Effects**” (PHB 205).

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap. For example, if two clerics cast bless on the same target, that character gains the spell’s benefit only once; he or she doesn’t get to roll two bonus dice.

"**Haste**" (PHB 250).

> When the spell ends, the target can't move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

So since the durations overlap and the most potent effect applies, would this mean that the newer Haste would supercede the older one thus negating the Lethargy when the first one ends or would the Hasted fellow still have a turn off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens with lethargy when Haste is cast again on a creature before first cast runs out?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78686/what-happens-with-lethargy-when-haste-is-cast-again-on-a-creature-before-first-c)

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find a question on this topic in spite of searching.